# Updating Access table from Excel using VBA. Getting "Current Recordset does not support updating" sometimes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I've got an excel workbook that pulls data from a linked access query, users add some data that has to be handled manually, then click a button to write the updated data to a table in Access. 90% of the time this code works perfectly for me, and for at least one of the users. Another user however, it only works 10% of the time without erroring out.

```
Sub SendtoAccess()
'send the updated data to the history table
Dim vDate As Date
Dim sMachine As String
Dim sShift As String
Dim sOperation As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

'Check that spreadsheet data is valid
If IsError(Cells(27, 5)) Then
    MsgBox "No OEE available, Please follow the steps and try again once an OEE % is displayed."
GoTo Done
End If

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'open database conection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\\<server>\database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"

'open recordset
rs.Open "Tbl_OEE_Daily_History", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

'grab operation type
sOperation = Cells(5, 2).Value

'grab shift
sShift = Cells(6, 2).Value

'grab machine
sMachine = Cells(7, 2).Value

'grab date
vDate = Range("cDate")
vDate = DateSerial(Year(vDate), Month(vDate), Day(vDate))

'filter to check for existing record
rs.Filter = "Completed_Date='" & vDate & "' AND Machine_Name='" & sMachine & "' AND Shift_ID='" & sShift & "'"

    If rs.EOF Then
        '^ No record found, lets create a new record

        'remove filter
        rs.Filter = ""

        'create new record
        rs.AddNew     <-- Fails here, sometimes, other times it works fine.
        rs("Completed_Date") = Cells(8, 2).Value
        rs("Machine_Name") = Cells(7, 2).Value
        rs("Operation") = Cells(5, 2).Value
        rs("Shift_ID") = Cells(6, 2).Value

    End If
        'Update fields for new/existing record
        rs("qty_Complete") = Cells(19, 5).Value
        rs("qty_Req'd") = (Cells(19, 5).Value + Cells(20, 5).Value)
        rs("qty_Scrap") = Cells(20, 5).Value
        rs("Ideal_Rate") = Cells(18, 5).Value
        rs("Downtime_mins") = Cells(17, 5).Value
        rs("Shift_Length_mins") = Cells(13, 5).Value
        rs("Pieces_per_Hour") = (Cells(27, 5).Value / (Cells(26, 5).Value / 60))
        rs("OEE") = Cells(7, 6).Value
        rs.Update

'clean up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Done:

End Sub
```

I'm at a loss.

Comment: What sort of error are you referring to?

Comment: run time error 3251 current recordset does not support updating

Comment: Could be maybe a problem of several users accessing same data at same time? Or maybe a permissions problem? Also, make sure the values entered are correct, because that could cause also an error of updating.